# Unable to customize cookie settings on stackoverflow.co

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, cookies, cookie-consent-dialog

I wanted to look something up about the company and the *About* link took me to the [new marketing site for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415962/new-official-secondary-domain-stackoverflow-co). I got the cookie privacy notice and it initially appeared as it's supposed to. However, when I clicked "Customize settings", everything broke:

[image: The Manage Consent Preferences box is too wide, is missing it's background, and seems to behind the vignetting instead of in front. Also, the initial cookie notice is still visible.]

The vignetting seems to be on top of everything as no buttons or links are clickable. The only way to do anything was to refresh the page.

I was able to reproduce this on [macOS 11.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) in:

- Firefox Version 98.0.1 (64-bit)
- Chrome Version 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Safari Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6)
- Opera Version:85.0.4341.39 (x86_64)

I do also have access to a Windows machine if you want me to test there as well, but this doesn't seem to be browser-specific.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 98.0.2 (64-bit) Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps, you can contact the staff using the contact page regarding this.

Comment: @RandomPerson I think they want us using Meta for bug reports like this. The timing was unfortunate with April Fool's Day taking most people's attention but now that it's a new work week maybe this point will get more eyes on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed.

I don't know if it was fixed by fixing [other problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/badly-escaped-html-results-in-plain-text-instead-of-markup-in-toast-notification) but the Cookie Settings modal now appears correctly, with the all the buttons working properly.

Checked on both my Windows and MacOS machines in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Yep, I raised this issue internally when I noticed it myself (before I saw this MSE post just now), and the person I informed responded to let me know that it had been fixed. (Another staff member may leave a comment or answer here with more details if there are any to provide.)

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks! I'll wait a while to see if that happens (I'll accept a staff member's answer if they leave one), otherwise I'll just accept my own in a couple of days.

Comment: @V2Blast looks like no staff member gave more details