# Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications (e.g. "You can&#39;t vote for your own post".)

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, popups, html-entities

There's an HTML escape bug that's reproducible network-wide.

Also [mentioned on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14654/), this is not just "ugly", but also causes prevents the link from being clicked, which is more important:

### Examples

[image: "You can't vote for your own post"]

[image: Thanks for your feedback]

[image: Don't forget you can mark this as accepted]

[image: You haven't voted on questions in a while]

I believe there could be other notifications of this kind that are also affected.

Comment: So, it's getting worse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXBcD.png

Comment: And apparently https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngELh.png just reported on [meta.su]

Comment: I suspect this bug was introduced when [this bug](/q/377741/289905) got fixed.

Comment: Now also reported on Meta Stack Overflow: ["You can&#39;t vote twice to delete a post"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417220/4642212).

Comment: [Don&#39;t forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd7cg.png) (sorry, reposted)

Comment: I found this as well over on Workplace SE where I got a message like "You haven't voted on a question in a while, don't forget to" (as opposed to just on answers) - except the apostrophe displayed as the HTML escape... I'm not going to repost, but wanted to note it happens there to

Comment: I [raised this in Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/html-formatting-issue-on-voting-button) and was directed here, so it persists across the estate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is now fixed, as are any other toast notifications that show that are related to voting.

> vote confirmation
> including html
> renders properly

Comment: But I can’t still vote for my own post! You have fixed the bug but not the core reason 

Comment: @nicael It gets worse. We still can't vote for our own posts several times! Absolutely outrageous! /s

Comment: Note, that if the same path is used anywhere near the community bulletin, it happens there too.

Comment: This bug isn't fully fixed, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382968/double-html-escape-in-lock-post-error-messages) is also a toast related to voting.