# Already-approved pending edit goes <br>

Tags: bug, status-completed, popups, character-escaping

Clicking the "Edit" link on a post when a pending suggested edit has already been approved results in this toast:

[image: This pending edit has already been approved/rejected.<br>Please refresh the page to see any changes.]

The HTML should not be escaped.

Prior art:

- [HTML is showing up in the pop-up when leaving a Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417474/208273)
- [Raw HTML displayed when ticking "this is not a duplicate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417430/208273)
- [HTML Tags showing in text area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417407/208273)
- [You need at least 15 <a href="/help/whats-reputation">reputation</a> to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417237/208273)
- [Problem with upvote warning message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417289/208273)
- [Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications (e.g. "You can&#39;t vote for your own post".)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743/165261)

Comment: That title is `<br>`illiant

Comment: “Goes br” - I see what you did here

Comment: I'm going to edit the cute title temporarily because I think it's causing our automation to fail to pull this into Jira.

Comment: Seems to have been the issue - re-editing the title hasn't caused the Zap to be triggered a second time (in general, title edits of a status-review post do cause multiple tickets for the same post). Not sure whether it's Zapier or Jira but probably good to know that some HTML in titles can cause something to fail. :)

Comment: @Catija It's almost surely Zapier; Jira has supported HTML tags in bug reports for years, at least.

Comment: Hmmm strange these tools don't take this as just a plain-text field. I can't think of any case where it would be helpfull to have html inside a title render.

Comment: When you want to have links, @Luuklag. There are several notification pop-ups that use them.

Comment: @Luuklag well they should give hackers some hope, right? So allowing HTML where plain text usually expected is a good way. ;)

Comment: @CodyGray why would you want a link from within the title? I was hinting at the Tools SE uses for their backlog tracking.

Comment: Re *"...any case where it would be helpful to have HTML inside a title render"*: Related: [MathJax in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378010/in-2022-what-actually-happens-to-a-candidate-question-for-the-hnq-when-mathjax)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

The issue has been fixed, and the fix is live in production now.

Comment: Prod build goes brr