# Double HTML Escape in Bounty Error Messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, locked, html-entities

There's a double HTML escape in the "locked post" message when awarding a bounty:

[image: Toast notification saying: "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on]

Comment: In the answer to the related but not duplicate [Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications (e.g. "You can&#39;t vote for your own post".)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/badly-escaped-html-results-in-plain-text-instead-of-markup-in-toast-notification), SE staff claimed this was fixed, but apparently this toast has _escaped_ their attention.

Comment: Regarding your last edit that removed the word "bounty", do you also see this problem when you try to upvote or downvote the answer? If not (as is the case with me) _and_ you can consistently reproduce this when attempting to reward the bounty to the locked answer (might want to test while you still have the chance :-D), then it should probably be clarified that this is specifically about awarding a bounty, and not general voting on a locked post.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine You're right. It is just for awarding the bounty. Reverted my edit.

Answer (score 3):

This issue should be resolved now - thank you for pointing it out!