# Fix HTML encoding in message on attempt to award a bounty for deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, bounties, error-message

Voting on deleted post leads to appearing of the following popup message:

> [image: ok]

But on pressing on bounty icon I got almost same message, but with a weird HTML encoding for `'`:

> [image: HTML encoded]

Comment: ._. The ego, bountying a link to your own profile :D

Comment: Very much related: [Double HTML Escape in Bounty Error Messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382968/double-html-escape-in-bounty-error-messages). Same, just for locked instead of deleted answer.

Comment: The latest installment of the [html entities issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=html+entities) ... I think SE should just [stop encoding these entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities) unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue should be resolved now - thank you for pointing it out!